# Creating Image with audio file and uploading to facebook

Tags: php, image, audio, animated-gif

I have googled for image format that supports audio also. I came to know that gif won't support audio.We need to do it in flash. Is there any image format which holds audio also?

We can show image with audio in web page with little work around using audio and image tag in html5.

But we need to implement this in PHP(Forget about language now) to combine audio with Image and share to facebook ? Is this possible?

Comment: Perhaps you mean video??

Comment: @user574632 I guess so.

Comment: No..absolutely not. Pure image. In some website u might have seen Image with play button at top.Music will play on clicking on that

Comment: Before understanding question dont press -1 button..Whoever it is ?

Comment: @stefun Thats not an image. It may contain an image, but it will be built with js, flash or similar.

Comment: Not me. But you cannot do it on facebook. Those things are built in image with script that play sound.

Comment: Yes.It is like image with audio separately. But that we can't share on facebook.Since it is separate.So I wanted to know if there is any image format which we can combine and share to facebook as image

Answer (score 1):

Upload to e.g soundcloud with image, that will give desired result, but its an audio file with image not vice versa, which is not possible.

Comment: We can upload audio to facebook through api?